# VNClassificationObservation color and position of object

Tags: ios, swift, vision

Does anyone know how can I extract color of (either full or partial) of a VNClassificationObservation object? Also what location/coordinates the object has in a still image. I have extracted the information like this:

```
let topClassifications = classifications.prefix(2)
let descriptions = topClassifications.map { classification in
print(String(format: "  (%.2f) %@", classification.confidence, classification.identifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

VNClassificationObservation has no property named color. I think you may be confused the datamodel that you work with the VNClassificationObservation object.

To illustrate, I have used inceptionv3 model in my Xcode project, I get a VNConfidence (basically it is a float type) type confidence and a string type identifier basically. A part of sample output of your code using inceptionv3 model will be;

**(0.173)** **pencil sharpener**

(0.064) reel

(0.056) chain saw, chainsaw

(0.051) hook, claw

(0.050) whistle

(0.040) padlock

(0.039) can opener, tin opener

(0.037) rule, ruler

(0.033) hair slide